# div sliding from right to full width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am building a style guide and I have a question about the transition of an element. Imagine you have a container with two elements besides each other. Both have 50% width. The left element should always be visible, but the right element slides from the right into its 50% width. How can I achieve something like this? I am a bit overwhelmed with the top, bottom, left, right, position:absolute properties.

The html would look like this:

```
<div class="module-container">
  <div class="first-element">
  <div class="second-element">
</div>
```

and the css like this:

```
.module-container {
    display: flex;
}

.first-element {
    width: 50%;
}

.second-element {
    width: 50%;
}
```

which properties does the second Element need in the first place? And which should I add via JavaScript after pressing, for instance, a button?

Answer (score 2):

try using jQuery and transitions

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('.secondElement').toggleClass("slide");
});
```

```css
.moduleContainer {
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.firstElement {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.secondElement {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    left: 100%;
    transition: left 1s;
}

.secondElement.slide {
    left: 0;
}

#btn {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moduleContainer">
  <div class="firstElement"></div>
  <div class="secondElement"></div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: You are the best! I replaced the jQuery-function with Javascript and it works beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative value for `margin-left` of the `.second-element`.

```css
.module-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module-container:hover .second-element {
  right: 0;
}

.first-element {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: #f90;
}

.second-element {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: #0f9;
  right: -50%;
  transition: all .6s ease;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-container">
  <div class="first-element"></div>
  <div class="second-element"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `position: absolute` and animate the `left` property

```css
.module-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module-container:hover .second-element {
  right: 0;
}

.first-element {
  width: 50%;
  background: #f90;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.second-element {
  background: #0f9;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-container">
  <div class="first-element"></div>
  <div class="second-element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the second element should not slide from the first element into its width. Imagine the second element as some kind of menu which slides in from the right side.

Comment: @dbljn Sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

```css
.moduleContainer {
    display: flex;
    height:100px;
}
.moduleContainer > * {
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.firstElement {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.secondElement {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    transition:width 0.3s ease;
}

.moduleContainer:hover .secondElement {
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="moduleContainer">
  <div class="firstElement"></div>
  <div class="secondElement"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it with pure CSS.I think it's good to have a bar, so the user can hover it and expand.I hope it will help you.

```css
     .moduleContainer{ display: flex;flex-flow: row nowrap; }
      .firstElement{ background-color:blueviolet;flex:1;height:100px;position:relative;max-width: 50%;  }
               
      .secondElement{ background-color:aqua;height:100px;flex:1;max-width:1%;position:relative;transition:1s ease;left:48%;  }
      .secondElement:hover{ background-color: chartreuse;left:0px;max-width:50%; }
```

```html
    <div class="moduleContainer">
        <div class="firstElement">First Element</div>
        <div class="secondElement"></div>
      </div>
```